# Optimization using lsqnonneg function of MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, data-modeling

I have to find value of x that minimizes norm of C*exp(2x)-d subject to x >= 0. I am trying to solve this problem in MATLAB. Both C and d are defined as vectors of dimension 1x180. Does anyone have any hint or suggestion on how to solve this problem using `lsqnonneg` function(or some other technique) in MATLAB? If it was just x instead of exp(2x) it could easily be solved by `lsqnonneg`! But because of exponential term in the problem I am not able to proceed further. I would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: what's the dimensionality of x?

Comment: It has the same dimensions as C and d,i.e 1x180.

Comment: so do you mean c.*exp(2*x)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First some math:
Define `y = exp(2*x)` then the constraint `x >=0` is equivalent to `y >= 1`. An equivalent minimization problem then is:

```
minimize(over y) norm(c.*y - d)
     subject to  y >= 1
```

There are a number of ways to do this in MATLAB. One cool way is to use CVX, if you download the [cvx convex optimization](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) package, the code would be:

```
n = 180;
cvx_begin
variable y(n)
minimize(norm(c .* y - d))
subject to:
1 <= y
cvx_end
```

Then of course you can do `x = log(y) / 2` to get the final value of `x`

Comment: However, if I have to solve the same problem without constraint, do I simply need to omit the "subject to" condition from the cvx code?

Comment: Omit the "subject to" condition and the constraint "1<= y" to eliminate the constraint. Be aware too that CVX only solves a subset of convex optimization problems that are provably convex according to CVX's ruleset.

Comment: I see :) I also wish to solve this problem numerically. Can you suggest good tutorials,etc that could help me solve these kind of problems numerically?

Comment: @zsha This is solving the problem numerically.